# Lanzar url SIN abrir el navegador

Tags: vb.net

Estoy buscando la forma de ejecutar una URL sin que se abra el navegador. Hasta ahora he utilizado el método:
`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(URL)` que abre la URL invocada en el navegador predeterminado.

Dicha URL envía un mensaje a un canal de telegram en  nombre de un bot especificado. No es necesario que muestre nada en el navegador, simplemente que lance la petición y el servidor telegram ejecute la acción.

La URL tiene un aspecto similar a este:
`https://api.telegram.org/bot[TokenDelBot]/sendMessage?chat_id=[TokenDelCanal]&text=Texto&parse_mode=HTML`

He encontrado la siguiente solución:

```
Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(URL)
request.GetResponse()
```

No se si es muy elegante pero da resultado; envía el mensaje y no abre el navegador.

Estoy buscando una solución alternativa porque el código que muestro en mi pregunta me funcionó un par de veces (no sé la razón) pero ahora me da un error

> The request was aborted: could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

Se agradece cualquier aportación.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola y bienvenidx a SOes. ¿Cuál es tu pregunta?

Comment: Cómo puedo invocar una URL desde vb.net sin que se abra el navegador?

Comment: O sea, quieres algo diferente al código que muestras ahí? El código que muestras falla?

Comment: Estoy buscando una solución alternativa por que el código que muestro en mi pregunta me funcionó un par de veces (no se la razón) pero ahora me da un error "The request was aborted: could not create SSL/TLS secure channel". Tienes alguna idea? Gracias

Comment: entonces.. la pregunta  es sobre ese error, no?

Answer (score 0):

Eso tiene pinta de que tu entorno cambió, actualizaste la versión de .NET Framework o algo más pasa.

Ese error se da porque el protocolo que tu cliente usa no es compatible con los que tiene habilitados el servicio que consumes. Por ejemplo, si usas SSLv3 o TLSv1.1 y Telegram sólo recibe TLSv1.3, vas a ver ese error.

Los protocolos por defecto en cada versión de .NET creo que van más o menos así

| Framework | Protocolo por defecto |
| --- | --- |
| 4.5 y anterior | SSL 3.0, TLS 1.0 |
| 4.6.x | TLS 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 |
| 4.7+ | Default del OS |

Y la [documentación oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls) da algunas pistas sobre cómo usar los protocolos correctos sin introducir problemas de seguridad.

Una solución rápida y que debes usar con cuidado es manualmente decirle a la petición qué protocolos probar para la conexión

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls13
       | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
       | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Ahí le dices cuáles probar (y si tienes un .NET viejo, posiblemente no tengas Tls13 y te va a fallar; si tienes uno mucho más reciente, posiblemente ya esté deprecado Tls11, etc).